# Why I can't install packages? apt-get says that I'm helding broken packages

Tags: wireless, apt, lubuntu

I am trying to install my wifi using:

> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

But I get this error:

> unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any ideas?

I am using Lubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a broken partial downloaded, try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and then do the

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and try to install the package again.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened because you have a *hold* on the package, that needs to be upgraded before installation of your desired package.

You can get a list of actual *hold* packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Then you can try to fix the problem you are facing with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f bcmwl-kernel-source
```

or

```
echo "package_name install" | dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

NB: `package_name` obtained via `dpkg --get-selections ...` command above.

Comment: Can you define hold please?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to fix the installation:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken --ignore-hold install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Unless something else is wrong, that should allow you to install the package.